# The best way to come up with the desired result in this query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables one has a set of ids and the other one has a set of ids and a user id as follows

**Client**

```
     id
  -----
    3
    4
    6
    7
    9
    11
```

**Business**

```
ClientId  |     userId
----------------------
 4            2
 4            3
 9            2
```

So basically i will have a parameter coming in @userId and if the @userId = 2 for example then that user has access to clientId    4 and 9 and all the others in the ClientId table but if say @userId = 5, this user can not access client ids 4 and 9 because they are restricted in the business table to only clients 2 and 3.

My desire result is a list of all the client ids a user can see (but must check that if a user id is specified in the business table and the user id is non of those there, that user id can not see the client ids in the business table when querying the clients table.

I am sorry it is so confusing.. i am having a hard time coming up with this one.. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

**The Result should be**

Assume User ID = 2

```
id
---
3
4
6
7
9
11
```

Assume User ID = 13

```
id
---
3
6
7
11
```

Because 4 and 9 are restricted to users 2 and 3 respectively.

Comment: Just to clarify - if userId 5 is passed in, they should be able to see ClientIDs 3, 6, 7, and 11?

Comment: Wow - this question doesn't make sense. Provide more data to illustrate what you want to do

Comment: Hmmm - on my next re-read, it sounds like as long as they're in the Business table, it doesn't matter which ClientID they're linked to, they get **all** Clients: *"if the @userId = 2 for example then that user has access to clientId 4 and 9 **and all the others** in the ClientId table"* Editing my answer to take this into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: based on my re-read, my understanding of the logic is this: return *all* Clients if the UserID is in the Business table, return all clients that don't exist in the Business table otherwise.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ClientId FROM Business WHERE UserId = @userId)
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT Id
  FROM Client
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT Id
  FROM Client
  WHERE Id NOT IN
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ClientId
    FROM Business
  )
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select DISTINCT ID from Client C
left join Business B on C.ID = B.ClientID
Where B.ClientID is null OR B.UserID = @UserID
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution than what I just posted. It's simpler and probably will have better performance too. Nice work @amit_g

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the query you want based on my interpretation of your question.

Here's the plain English description of what the query does: Remove from the list of all Clients, the clients that are restricted by the Business table. Then add the list of Clients that the user has explicit access to.

```
declare @userid int =5 
(
 select Id from Client 
 except
 select clientId from Business 
)
union 
select clientId from Business where userId = @userId
```